# Choosing between Terminal and CMD for console apps on Windows: Understanding the default settings

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, terminal

Windows released Terminal, the 'new cmd'. The problem is, I want a console app to open in conhost.exe (cmd), because it needs to be able to change the window size and do other things that Terminal can't(in c#). I know I can change the default cmd in settings, and so the same setting maybe set to 'let windows decide'.the question is that I would like to know what makes Windows choose one or the other? *[make with google translate]*

I read the doc and unfortunately I couldn't find anything

Comment: A console app doesn't choose which terminal it opens in, the OS chooses (if you double click the exe) or it is started within an existing shell.